# How to call a panel from a button with ActionListener

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I'm making a simple program that jumps from panel to panel and am using an actionlistener Button to make the jump. What kind of method or operation do I use to jump from panel to panel?

I tried to use setVisible(true); under the action listener, but I get just a blanks screen. Tried using setContentPane(differentPanel); but that doesn't work.

```
ackage Com.conebind.Characters;
import Com.conebind.Tech.TechA16;
import Com.conebind.Overviews.OverviewA16;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Char_A16 extends JFrame {

    private JButton combosButton16;
    private JButton techButton16;
    private JButton overviewButton16;
    private JLabel Image16;
    private JPanel panel16;
    private JPanel panelOverviewA16;
    public Char_A16() {
        overviewButton16.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                OverviewA16 overview16 = new OverviewA16();
             overview16.setVisible(true);
             overview16.pack();
             overview16.setContentPane(new Char_A16().panelOverviewA16);
            }
        });
        techButton16.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                //Todo
            }
        });

        }

    private void createUIComponents(){

        Image16 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Android 16.png"));
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Android 16");
        frame.setContentPane(new Char_A16().panel16);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);}
}
```

The setContentPane(OverviewA16) doesn't work because there's not an object that defines the panel.

Comment: Use a CardLayout to add the panels to a master panel.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/719it8encpj8leh/CardDemo.zip?dl=1) showing how to use CardLayout with IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer.

[image: CardLayout 1]

[image: CardLayout 2]

The main form has a method that switches between 2 forms displayed inside it:

```
  public void showPanel(String id) {
    final CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cardPanel.getLayout();
    cl.show(cardPanel, id);
  }
```

Both forms are added to the card layout during the main form initialization:

```
FormOne one = new FormOne();
one.setParentForm(this);
cardPanel.add(one.getPanel(), FORM_ONE);
FormTwo two = new FormTwo();
two.setParentForm(this);
cardPanel.add(two.getPanel(), FORM_TWO);
final CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cardPanel.getLayout();
cl.show(cardPanel, FORM_ONE);
```

A reference to the main parent form is passed to these 2 forms using `setParentForm()` method so that `FormOne` and `FormTwo` classes can access the `showPanel()` method of the `MainForm`.

In a more basic case you may have a button or some other control that switches the forms 
located directly on the `MainForm`, then you may not need passing the main form reference to the subforms, but it can be still useful depending on your app logic.