# Can I use buttons to make frames go between visible and invisible?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

So I'm currently doing a project and I want to know whether or not what I'm doing is possible or not. My idea was to create 3 frames, one for each database table. I would then have a button with "Customer" and when clicked it would turn all the other frames and its components invisible while keeping it's own frame visible. Is this possible to do or is there an easier way? Is it possible to create 3 different classes for each frame and link them? I left my code below so you can get a better of what I'm trying.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main(){
        // Attach window listener
        addWindowListener(new WindowCloser()); // Just in-case it's needed

        // Adding first customer panel
        JPanel pCustomerL = new JPanel();
        pCustomerL.setBounds(0,0,750,750);
        pCustomerL.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        // Adding second customer panel
        JPanel pCustomerR = new JPanel();
        pCustomerR.setBounds(750,0,750,750);
        pCustomerR.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        // Adding first product panel
        JPanel pProductL = new JPanel();
        pProductL.setBounds(0,0,750,750);
        pProductL.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        // Adding second product panel
        JPanel pProductR = new JPanel();
        pProductR.setBounds(750,0,750,750);
        pProductR.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        // Adding first invoice panel
        JPanel pInvoiceL = new JPanel();
        pInvoiceL.setBounds(0,0,750,750);
        pInvoiceL.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        // Adding second invoice panel
        JPanel pInvoiceR = new JPanel();
        pInvoiceR.setBounds(750,0,750,750);
        pInvoiceR.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        // Button Listener
        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
        // Adding "Customer" Button
        JButton b = new JButton("Invoice");
        b.addActionListener(listener);
        add(b);
        b.setBounds(1300,10,150,35);
        // Adding "Product" Button
        b = new JButton("Product");
        b.addActionListener(listener);
        add(b);
        b.setBounds(1150,10,150,35);
        // Adding "Invoice" Button
        b = new JButton("Customer");
        b.addActionListener(listener);
        add(b);
        b.setBounds(1000,10,150,35);

        // Frame Settings
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(1500,750);

        // Customer Panel
        this.add(pCustomerL);
        this.add(pCustomerR);
        // Product Panel
       // this.add(pProductL);
       // this.add(pProductR);
        // Invoice Panel
        this.add(pInvoiceL);
        this.add(pInvoiceR);

        // Customer Panel Settings
        pCustomerL.setVisible(false);
        pCustomerR.setVisible(false);
        // Product Settings
        pProductL.setVisible(true);
        pProductR.setVisible(true);
        // Invoice settings
        pInvoiceL.setVisible(false);
        pInvoiceR.setVisible(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Listener for buttons
    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            String buttonLabel = evt.getActionCommand();
        }
    }

    // Listener for window
    class WindowCloser extends WindowAdapter {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) { System.exit(0);}
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}
```

}

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56140714/104891 for the sample project.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to control more than one panel in the same windows application in Java, the most recommended option is to use the **JTabedPane** component. In it, you can set the different panels and hide / show them more easily depending on your needs.

```
 // In this case the look and feel renders the title for the tab.
 tabbedPane.addTab("Tab", myComponent);
 // In this case the custom component is responsible for rendering the
 // title of the tab.
 tabbedPane.addTab(null, myComponent);
 tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, new JLabel("Tab"));
```

Try to do more research on this if you are interested.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html